# How can I make a control collapse and disappear?

Tags: gradio

I want a column holding a control to collapse when a button is clicked.

```
with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    with gr.Row():
        with gr.Column(scale=1, min_width=0):          
            html_element = gr.HTML()

        with gr.Column(scale=0, min_width=20):
            btn_toggle = gr.Button()

        with gr.Column(scale=2):
            usr_txt = gr.Textbox()
            
        
        btn_toggle.click(handle_toggle, btn_toggle, html_element)
```

I'm currently struggling with implementing the click event for the 'btn_toggle' button. The goal is to have the first column collapse when this button is clicked. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.